# Github permission denied (publickey) after I set up SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh, terminal, gitlab

I'm trying to transfer my Gitlab repository to Github, but when I try to push it up (according to the various guides), I always get the error: `Permission denied (publickey).`

I have gone through the Github tutorial of adding a SSH key locally then to my Github account multiple times, but it still doesn't work. Here is the output of some of the various commands.

(I already did the keygen command)

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 84168

$ ssh-add -l -E md5
The agent has no identities.

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_rsa: <my-passphrase>
Identity added: /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_rsa)

$ ssh-add -l -E md5
4096 MD5:0c:44:3d:28:de:17:71:e5:29:18:bf:a1:8c:8j:mf:3c /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/isaiahmayerchak/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

On Github, the SSH key I added matches my local one exactly, but on Github it says it hasn't been used yet.

I have already done setting the github config for my username and email. I have also tried `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -vT git@github.com`
 but that didn't do me any good either. I really need to transfer this repository for work in the next 2 days. None of the troubleshooting articles I have seen have helped; they all assume that `ssh -vT git@github.com` will work after their steps but it doesn't for me. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you try adding manually ?

Comment: Did you add the key or fingerprint?

Comment: I'm not sure what the fingerprint is, but I have added the key to Github manually (the only way I have added the key is manually)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Mint Linux 19 and although the details are not precisely the same as yours, I wanted to share my experience for the benefit of others:

After running ssh-keygen, adding my key to my github account via html, and successfully connecting to github via:

```
 ssh -vT git@github.com
```

I then encountered a Permission Denied error when I tried to clone a repository via ssh, using this syntax:

```
git clone ssh://USERNAME@github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY
```

I tried all of the solutions in the comments on this question as of July 3, 2020, but nothing helped. Then I went to github and found [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey)

Which told me to:

> Always use the "git" user
>
> All connections, including those for remote URLs, must be made as the
> "git" user. If you try to connect with your GitHub username, it will
> fail:
>
> $ ssh -T GITHUB-USERNAME@github.com
>
> > Permission denied (publickey).
>
> If your connection failed and you're using a remote URL with your
> GitHub username, you can change the remote URL to use the "git" user.

After following this instruction, I connected via SSH without error.

The syntax that worked for me was:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY
```

Answer (score 0):

Add you local machine ssh key manually into github profile.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Copy the output of above command and paste it to "Github -> Settings -> SSH and GPG Key -> New SSH Key".

Comment: This is what I originally did to put the key into Github; it's already there

Comment: flysaiah : Can you remove the existing key and try adding it once again ?

Comment: I have tried 3 different times, including generating a new key as well. I have compared the two and they are the same

Comment: How did you generated a new ?.

Comment: ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my-email-address@example.com"

Comment: Have you entered any password, while creating the key ?

Comment: I had to enter a passphrase when generating a new key, but I did not get prompted for it during the `ssh -vT` command

Comment: Create a new key and just place enter when it ask for passpharse.

Comment: I just re-did the entire process without a passphrase as you suggested, but unfortunately there is no change in result, I still get the same denial.

Comment: What is global config of git ? Make sure both the email id's are same.

Comment: Yes, the config email id is exactly what it should be, as well as the username